# How can I prepare a Group Stacked Bar Chart in Highcharts using multiple and different types of data?

Tags: highcharts

I'm going to prepare a stacked bar charts report using highcharts. The problem is my data types are different, like

Main Data Group Is A,

A Consists of x & Y

Ax is the x part of A consists of Ax1 and Ax2.
Ay is the y part of A consists of Ay1 and Ay2. The Matrix is given below:

```
A = Ax + Ay
Ax = Ax1 + Ax2
Ay= Ay1 + Ay2
```

How can I prepare one single Group Stacked Bar Chart in where 3 BAR will represent the value of  A, Ax and Ay with Highcharts using the above mentioned data table.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you can create JSON like this:

```
A = { 
    Ax: [Ax1, Ax2], 
    Ay: [Ay1, Ay2] 
}
```

that will mean you are on a good way.

Now the question remains: how should be displayed? For example: http://jsfiddle.net/gqMLk/ (but where should be third bar of A? ).